# Probability of 2 in first 5 of 7

Tags: probability

> There are 5 cards of type $A$ and 2 cards of type $B$. The cards are shuffled and 5 of them are drawn. What is the probability of the following outcomes:
>
> (a) The 5 cards contain no cards of type B;
>
> (b) The 5 cards contain 1 card of type B;
>
> (c) The 5 cards contain 2 cards of type B?

Comment: What have you attempted?  Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The five cards contain no cards of type B:

$$\frac{5 \choose 5}{7 \choose 5} = \frac{1}{21}$$

2. The five cards contain one card of type B:

$$\frac{{5 \choose 4}{2 \choose 1}}{7 \choose 5} = \frac{10}{21}$$

3. The five cards contain two cards of type B:

$$\frac{{5 \choose 3}{2 \choose 2}}{7 \choose 5} = \frac{10}{21}$$

Indeed, $\frac{1 + 10 + 10}{21} = 1$.

Answer (score 2):

No B means 5 A's, so this is the same as the probability of drawing all 5 A's. 
So the first A is drawn with probability 5/7. The next one with 4/6, and so on:

$ P$(no B's, or in other words, 5 A's) = $\frac{5}{7} \dot{}\frac{4}{6} \dot{} \frac{3}{5} \dot{} \frac{2}{4} \dot{} \frac{1}{3}  = \frac{5!2!}{7!} = $ 1 in $\binom{7}{5} = \frac{1}{21} $

You can use the choose function for the other two cases as well; use the same logic about the probability of each draw having the card you want.